# Tkinter not working mac osx el capitan

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-2.x, osx-elcapitan

I was trying to import using Python2.7 the module Tkinter in MAC OSX el capitan Version 10.11, but I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
       import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

I would like to get a solution for this problem, because seems to be an instalation problem and the webpage ActiveTCL seems to be broken

Comment: That was from Python 3 and the OS is Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/543451/configure-tkinter-for-python3-4-2)

Comment: Those solutions are for UBUNTU, i am looking for MAC EL CAPITAN

Comment: I ran into same problem. Looks like system python2.7 in El Capitan doesn't have tkinter installed. Works fine when using homebrew version of python3.