# Fixing Python 3 tkinter issues on Mac with a virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I **think** the short version of this question is: How do I get a `virtualenv` running Python 3.5 to point to the correct version of ActiveTcl on a Mac?

---

Here's the longer version:

I'm trying to run [this Korg Electribe sample editor project](https://github.com/JonathanTaquet/Oe2sSLE) on a Mac.  The author has only tested it on Windows, and based on the screenshots, it appears to work.  I've been able to run the basic python script fine, but [as I mention in an issue that I've opened](https://github.com/JonathanTaquet/Oe2sSLE/issues/2), the full window turns black after loading a file.

After doing some research, I've found that there is a [known issue with Aqua Cocoa Tk](http://bugs.python.org/issue19373), and python.org has [provided some instrunctions](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) about how to fix `tkinter` for Mac OS 10.9 and up.  I've attempted installing both of the suggested ActiveTcl (8.5.18.0) as well as the newer 8.6.x.x version without success.

I'm pretty sure this is a different issue than [Tkinter not working mac osx el capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369085/tkinter-not-working-mac-osx-el-capitan), since the script does run, and the window is drawn properly on launch.  It's only after I've attempted to load a `.all` file (there's a sample file in the Github issue) that the screen goes black.

After some more research, I've found this question that seems related, but is specific to Windows: [TKinter in a Virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884075/tkinter-in-a-virtualenv)

I'm under the impression that if I can figure out what to set `TCL_LIBRARY` to, that I'll be able to make some head-way, but I can't seem to find that information for the packages listed on python.org.

Somewhat related, it would also seem to be helpful if I could figure out *which* version of Tcl/Tk that `tkinter` is pointing to from within Python, so if anyone could help with that as well, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: There have been some updates and comments to the Github issue linked above, but I haven't followed up to see if the issue is actually fixed, or what the cause was.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in using tkinter in a python3 virtualenv on OSX 10.13 by :

- installing the official OSX Python 3 from https://www.python.org/
- installing activeTcl from https://www.activestate.com/activetcl
- creating a new virtualenv

  ```
  mkvirtualenv myenv --python=python3
  ```
- locating the tkinter location in the Python3 directory. For me it was here :

  ```
  /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter
  ```
- creating a symbolic link in the virtualenv library pointing to the tkinter location

  ```
  cd ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6
  ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter tkinter
  ```

Comment: YES! you finally ended my aimless wandering about the internet. This was an issue with a [virtualfish](https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish) environment on ubuntu 18.04. My magic incantation turned out to be `ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ~/.virtualenvs/science/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. `science` is the virtualenv name; modify for your purposes as needed.